# Is it possible to modify source code with ant?

Tags: java, ant, preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I would like to do conditional compilation in a program of mine. I know that if you declare a public static final boolean the compiler will ignore the branch that is not traversed. Is it possible to have an ant target change a variable before building the program?

For example if I have:

`final public static boolean windows = false;`

I would like two ant targets: Windows and Mac. 
I would like the command

  `ant windows`
 
to change the boolean to true, while

  `ant mac`
 
leaves the variable as is.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this really necessary?  Why not just load the boolean once at startup from a configuration file? Think about how much you gain (the evaluation of a non-static non-final boolean variable at runtime has no real cost), versus the impact this has on your build process.

Comment: @Thilo - The point is to not have the code in the jar at all. Property file doesn't really achieve this, good idea nonetheless.

Comment: If it's large swaths of code, the delocalization caused by the dead code in the middle can be pretty significant in terms of performance.

Comment: Consider the OO solution.  Create an interface with a separate implementation class for each platform.  Then only instantiate the class of the appropriate platform.  Java won't load the classes for the other platforms if they are never instantiated, and thus they won't take up memory or ruin localization.  You could even distribute the classes for each platform in separate jar files so that you can choose which pieces to distribute to which users.

Comment: there are valid cases for what you want to do. It's called "source code instrumentation" and there are tools allowing to do that (not Ant AFAIK but surely an Ant Task could be made to perform source code instrumentation). However the use case you gave is not one of them :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get Ant to modify a properties file, and then you can read this file in your application pretty easily:
`new Properties(new FileInputStream("filename" / new File(filename))`),
and read properties using:
`Boolean isWindows = new Boolean(properties.getProperty("windows"))`
or:
`String os = properties.getProperty("os")`.

You can use the Ant `PropertyFile` task for doing this: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html.

*Edit: here's an alternative using another task if you absolutely must edit the source code file using Ant:*

`<replaceregexp file="blah.java" match="public static final boolean WINDOWS = \"(.*)\"" replace="public static final boolean WINDOWS = \"" + ${properties.windows} + "\""  />` 
*-- replace the code as your own as required. See http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html for details.*

Comment: +1. This should be property, not compiled in. The performance benefit of having the compiler strip out the un-used code is negligible.

Comment: I noticed you need to use &quot; for ". Using \" does not work.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the other answers carefully and see if there is a better solution for you. However, Ant does have a task to replace text in files. For example:

<replace file="${src}/MyFile.java" token="boolean windows=true" value="boolean windows=false"/>

Answer (score 1):

Skip ant and property files etc, Java already does this!

Use something like System.getProperty("os.name");

Comment: Windows detection was just an example

Answer (score 1):

The properties and the replace tasks should get you what you need.
I concur that finding a different approach is a good idea.

However if for some reason the built in tasks will not get you
what you need, it is pretty easy to write a custom task for ant.
See http://ant.apache.org/manual/develop.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also provide command-lind value as an argument while calling Java-main program from Ant.

For eg. `ant -f build.xml "YouranttaskName" -Doperatingsys="windows"`

Inside build.xml

```
<target name="YouranttaskName">
<java classname="javaclassname" fork="true" >
<arg value="${operatingsys}" />
</java>
</target>
```

Inside java -main method this argument-value will be available in same order .i.e. args[0] contains "Windows".

You can write your logic by  considering that what is your default OS value, as user may not provide commandline argument and then set '`boolean flag'` parameter accordingly.